# How do I remove strings using wildcards in wordpress post's content?

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin

This is my first question, so pardon me the ethics the first time.
I am running a wordpress website., and I need to remove strings from all posts.

The string to be removed 
`<li class="dZip">(combination of characters, even special)Download ZIP</a></li>`

It varies according to the post. I could use a plugin, But plugins don't accept wildcards.

I tried running this in my phpmyadmin, but I don't see any result.,

This is the query I ran through phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`,'<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="(.*?)\.zip" title="(.*?)\.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>','')
```

Example string :

```
<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="https://example.com/demo/file.zip" title="file.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>
```

I need to remove this whole string, with the link and filetile as varying strings.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.24.

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660574/5193536  because mysql 5 doesn't have REGex_REPLACE

Comment: I think it must be resolved in code before insert into MySQL

Comment: Are there any wordpress functions to do this?. or any php functions?

Comment: @nbk Hi, I just upgraded to a website with updated mysql, Now the version is 8.0.18.

Comment: please make some example rows to explain exactly what you want to find and removed.

Comment: @nbk hi, Thank you in advance, I have updated the question with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

**But make a BACKUP before doing this Update on your database**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="https://example.com/demo/file.zip" title="file.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>b',
'<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip">(.*)download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>','');
```

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="https://example.com/demo/file.zip" title="file.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>b',
> '<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip">(.*)download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>','');
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE('a<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="https://example.com/demo/file.zip" title="file.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>b',
> '<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip">(.*)download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>','' |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ab                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa3bf0bc9b7b5951cad77457c8bfa255)*